# Leaflet - Change and revert polygon feature style

Tags: leaflet, styles, polygon, overlap

I make a little app using leaflet to display information about polygons.
Here's how the code works :

- A crosshair is displayed in the center of the screen on top of the map
- When map pans, crosshair remains in the center on the screen
- When crosshair overlaps a polygon, polygon information is displyed in a div
- the purpose of this system is to help polygon selecting on mobile for very small polygons

I came up with the following app : https://www.laurentgontier.com/Crosshair/

I need to be able to change polygon style when it is overlaped by crosshair and revert to default style when crosshair leaves polygon.

so far, I wasn't able to achieve this.

Here's the part of code :

```
//Geojson layer display     
var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("map.geojson",{       
onEachFeature: onEachFeature
});       
geojsonLayer.addTo(map);

//Crosshair display
var crosshairIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'Cible.png',
    iconSize:     [30, 30], // size of the icon
    iconAnchor:   [15, 15], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
});
crosshair = new L.marker(map.getCenter(), {icon: crosshairIcon, clickable:false});
crosshair.addTo(map);

// Move the crosshair to the center of the map when the user pans
map.on('move', function(e) {
crosshair.setLatLng(map.getCenter());
});

// Move the crosshair to the center of the map when the user pans
map.on('moveend', function(e) {
var hasHit = false;

var newCenter = map.getCenter();

geoJsonLayers.forEach(function(layer){
var currLayerFeature = layer.feature;
var layerPlace = currLayerFeature.properties.Place;

var layerCoordinates = currLayerFeature.geometry.coordinates[0]

var xp = [], yp =[];
for(var i = 0; i<layerCoordinates.length; i++){
xp.push(layerCoordinates[i][0]); yp.push(layerCoordinates[i][1]);
}

if(checkPointForHit(xp, yp , newCenter.lng, newCenter.lat)){
displayPlace.innerHTML = layerPlace; hasHit = true}

})
if(!hasHit)displayPlace.innerHTML = 'Not overlaping polygon'
});


function checkPointForHit(xp/*array of xpointsOfPolygon*/, yp /*array of ypointsOfPolygon*/, x, y) { 
var i, j, c = 0, npol = xp.length; 
for (i = 0, j = npol-1; i < npol; j = i++) { 
if ((((yp[i] <= y) && (y < yp[j])) || 
((yp[j] <= y) && (y < yp[i]))) && 
(x < (xp[j] - xp[i]) * (y - yp[i]) / (yp[j] - yp[i]) + xp[i])) { 
c =!c; 
} 
} 
return c; 
}
```

Any idea about that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [turfjs](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@turf/turf@5.1.6/turf.min.js) library and then use `booleanContains`:

```
map.on('moveend', function(e) {
    var hasHit = false;

    geojsonLayer.resetStyle()

    geoJsonLayers.forEach(function(layer){
        var layerPlace = layer.feature.properties.Place;

        if(turf.booleanContains(layer.toGeoJSON(),crosshair.toGeoJSON())){
            displayPlace.innerHTML = layerPlace; 
            hasHit = true;
            layer.setStyle({color: 'red'});
        }

    })
    if(!hasHit){
        displayPlace.innerHTML = 'Not overlaping polygon';
    }
});
```

When you change the event from `moveend` to `move` the color is updated while moveing

**Add DOM Script**

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@turf/turf@5.1.6/turf.min.js';    

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);


map.on('move moveend', function(e) {
    var hasHit = false;

    var newCenter = map.getCenter();
    geojsonLayer.resetStyle()

    geoJsonLayers.forEach(function(layer){
        var layerPlace = layer.feature.properties.Place;


        if(turf.booleanContains(layer.toGeoJSON(),crosshair.toGeoJSON())){
            displayPlace.innerHTML = layerPlace; 
            hasHit = true;
            layer.setStyle({color: 'red'});
        }

    })
    if(!hasHit){
        displayPlace.innerHTML = 'Not overlaping polygon';
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you ! I didn't know about this library. I added Turf library to my document and replaced your map.on('moveend') function by yurs but it doesn't seem to work.<script src='https://unpkg.com/@turf/turf/turf.min.js'></script>
<script>

Comment: @Laurent I updated the code. It adds the turf script in js and with that it is working for me.